# Easiest way to get Surface Pro built-in WiFi working?

Tags: wireless, drivers, surface

Is there a `.deb` that I can download from another computer and transfer over USB to get Surface Pro WiFi working? I'd rather not tinker with modprobe, and I don't have a USB Internet adapter.

Comment: What kind of wifi adapter does it have? Run `lspci -nn` and paste in in your post.

Comment: might help to mention which version of ubuntu you are using as well

Comment: 13.04, or 12.04.

Comment: You should probably follow https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1165938 for updates on when, if ever, this configuration could be supported through a standard package install.